# Search a value for a given key in a HashMap

Tags: java

How do you search for a key in a `HashMap`? In this program, when the user enters a key the code should arrange to search the hashmap for the corresponding value and then print it.

Please tell me why it's not working.

```
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.; import java.lang.;

public class Hashmapdemo  
{
    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
        String value; 
        HashMap hashMap = new HashMap(); 
        hashMap.put( new Integer(1),"January" ); 
        hashMap.put( new Integer(2) ,"February" ); 
        hashMap.put( new Integer(3) ,"March" ); 
        hashMap.put( new Integer(4) ,"April" ); 
        hashMap.put( new Integer(5) ,"May" ); 
        hashMap.put( new Integer(6) ,"June" ); 
        hashMap.put( new Integer(7) ,"July" );  
        hashMap.put( new Integer(8),"August" );  
        hashMap.put( new Integer(9) ,"September");  
        hashMap.put( new Integer(10),"October" );  
        hashMap.put( new Integer(11),"November" );  
        hashMap.put( new Integer(12),"December" );

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);  
        System.out.println("Enter an integer :");  
        int x = scan.nextInt();  
        value = hashMap.get("x");  
        System.out.println("Value is:" + value);  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Make sure to accept the answer that answers your question by hitting the "tick" next to it.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Just call [`get`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#get(java.lang.Object)):

```
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("x", "y");

String value = map.get("x"); // value = "y"
```

Answer (score 4):

To decalare the hashMap use this:

```
 HashMap<Integer,String> hm=new HashMap<Integer,String>();
```

To enter the elements in the HashMap:

```
 hm.put(1,"January");
 hm.put(2,"Febuary");
```

before searching element first check that the enter number is present in the hashMap for this use the method containsKey() which will return a Boolean value:

```
 if(hm.containsKey(num))
 {
    hm.get(num);
 }
```

Comment: How does this improve on [Gagan's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32823144/354577) from nearly five years ago?

Answer (score 2):

You wrote

```
HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();
...
int x = scan.nextInt();
value = hashMap.get("x");
```

must be:

```
Map<Integer, String> hashMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
...
int x = scan.nextInt();
value = hashMap.get(x);
```

EDIT or without generics, like said in the comments:

```
int x = scan.nextInt();
value = (String) hashMap.get(new Integer(x));
```

Comment: still it gives erroe saying:cast...get(...)to string

Comment: here value is a string variable

Comment: the get method returns an object. You have to cast it to a string like this: value = (String) hashMap.get(new Integer(x)); Or you use so called "generics" to tell the compiler that there are only strings in your map, like I did in my example using "<Interger, String>"

Answer (score -1):

//If you want the key to be integer then you will have to declare the hashmap //as below :

```
HashMap<Integer, String> map = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
map.put(0, "x");
map.put(1, "y");
map.put(2, "z");
```

//input a integer value x

```
String value = map.get(x);
```