# Checking variable value with hashmap data in java

Tags: java, hashmap, hashset

I need to check my variable value directly with hashmap values.

My hashmap values has two entry both in string and I need to check my variables value with first entry of hashmap.

Smaller version of code is above.

```
HashMap<String , String> directory = new HashMap<String , String>();
    directory.put("AFG","Afghanistan");
    directory.put("GBR","United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland");
    directory.put("IDN","Indonesia");
    directory.put("IND","India");
```

Next i have used scanner class to get user's value.Then what i need to know is how to compare this user's value with first entry of hashmap that is i.e AFG , GBR , etc

Sample code of whole program is :

```
import java.util.*;

public class hashmapdemo {
public static void main(String args[]) {

    HashMap<String , String> directory = new HashMap<String , String>();
    directory.put("AFG","Afghanistan");
    directory.put("GBR","United Kingdom of Great Britain and Northern Ireland");
    directory.put("IDN","Indonesia");
    directory.put("IND","India");

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String name = sc.nextLine();
    System.out.println(name);

    // comparing logic ?

}
}
```

Comment: what will be user's input? key or value?

Comment: there is no order in hashmap, if order is important you should look into other data structure.

Comment: user's input will be key part that is IND , etc and i need to compare it with hashmap value @Saravana

Comment: No, Order is not important for me i just want to compare that user's input with hashmap value @EduardoDennis

Comment: `directory.get(key)` will return the value

Comment: Have a look at this similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3051486/search-a-value-for-a-given-key-in-a-hashmap). You get the value for the key with `directory.get(name);`

Comment: you said you have to compare with the **first** entry of the hashmap

Comment: You seem to mix entry, key and value which makes your question hard to understand

Comment: First entry among all entry of hashmap @EduardoDennis

Comment: Thank you very much @hofmeister 
I get your my answer..

Comment: I am sorry for fixing up of data by writing entry and hashmap entry etc... @NicolasFilotto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, to prevent a nullPointer exception you want to make sure your `HashMap` contains the users input key with:

`directory.containsKey(key)`

if that is successful then you can return that value of the corresponding key:

`return directory.get(key);`

```
String key = sc.nextLine();


       if(directory.containsKey(key))
       {
           return directory.get(key);
       }
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need

```
directory.get(name);
```

This will return the name of the country.

In order to avoid NullPointerException:

```
String countryName = directory.get(name);
if (countryName != null) {
    // use your countryName variable
}
```

This has better performance than calling another unnecessary method like `directory.containsKey(name);`

Comment: I would presume because you need to check if the map contains the key before trying to directly access it.

Comment: Calling directory.get(name) will throw a NullPointerException if the key doesn't exist the program will error out before you check if the value is null

Comment: @SamOrozco please test it. It just RETURNS null. It does not throw any exception.